# How do I dualboot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my RST enabled computer?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows, rst

I was looking forward to install Linux on my computer (processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U).

I had created a bootable drive, and did the necessary BIOS settings like: *safe boot*, *boot mode* etc.

I logged into my computer, but when I tried to install Ubuntu, it said "**Turn off RST**" and gave me a link to Ubuntu's page, where they explained how to overcome this problem with the registry editor and then using `AHCI` for `SATA` options by going to the main tab in your BIOS and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>.

Problem: I can't find the tab `Main` in my BIOS, I've got others like Information, Boot, Security, Config...

Is there another way to change my SATA options to AHCI?

Comment: Try Config. Anyway it's your own computer firmware settings we're talking about so please check your user's manual first. And keep in mind that if your dual-booting with Windows, changing the drive mode from Intel RST to AHCI without installing AHCI support in Windows first will result in an unbootable Windows.

Comment: I've tried to ctrl + s on every tab, no setting appears...
And about the warning: Thank you!

Comment: There is [documentation](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347) regarding installing Ubuntu on RST enabled computers. See if those are helpful for your case. You need to provide information about what type of hardware you use and if possible, link to the Ubuntu help doc you were using.